# Stateless session in Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

We have some REST calls which performs quite massive operations on data (but not via Spring-Data). Because of that we would like to have Stateless Session for them.

Question is how to make it properly in Spring Boot with Hibernate and JPA?
Because when I make simple test where I call some repository :

```
@Repository 
public class HelloRepository {

  @PersistenceContext   
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public boolean checkIfTransactionIsOpened() {
    return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).isOpen();   
  }

}
```

it gives me always true. I have feeling that session there should not be opened as I want to use Stateless Session.

Controller and Service do not do anything special. No @Transactional annotations etc:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}

@RestController
public class HelloRest {
  @Autowired
  private HelloService helloService;

  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public ResponseEntity<Boolean> sayHello() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(helloService.checkIfTransactionIsOpened());
  }
}

@Service
public class HelloService {
  @Autowired
  private HelloRepository helloRepository;

  public boolean checkIfTransactionIsOpened() {
    return helloRepository.checkIfTransactionIsOpened();
  }
}
```

So question is: HOW to inform my app "please do not open session there I want to use stateless session"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

We're considering [switching that to false by default in Spring Boot 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7107)